# Minimum time to shift given weight boxes from one position to other when capacity of machines are given

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given n boxes of different weights and m machines of different weight carrying capacity. Find the minimum time required to move all boxes.

Machines Capacities : C[0] , C[1] , C[2],........C[m-1].

Box Weights : W[0] , W[1] , W[2] .... W[n].

Each machine takes 1 minute to carry one time. 
What can be the optimal approach recursive approach will be to try assigning current box to given machine and not assign and recur for rest of thee boxes.

Note: A single machine  can carry boxes multiple times , Each round trip takes exactly 1 unit time.

Comment: Can a machine carry boxes multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the machines in descending order of weight carrying capacities.

Sort the boxes in increasing order of weights.

Now, add boxes one by one to each machine until the weight carrying capacity of the machine exceeds.

When it exceeds then move to the next machine.

**Pseudocode:**

```
W[] //sorted in increasing order
C[] //sorted in decreasing order

i = 0 //pointer for box
j = 0 //pointer for machine
curr_weight = 0
time_taken = 0
while i<n:
  curr_weight = curr_weight + W[i]
  if curr_weight > C[j]:
     curr_weight = 0
     j = j + 1
     time_taken = time_taken + 1
  else
     i = i + 1
end while

print time_taken + 1
```

*Check for boundary cases. For example if `j` exceeds `m-1`*

**Edit:** In case the same machine can carry multiple times

Maintain a sorted *STACK* for machines [sorted in descending order]. As soon as a machine gets full and leaves for transportation, pop the machine from *STACK* and enqueue it in a *QUEUE*. As soon as a machine is ready to carry again(after it has returned from the transportation job), dequeue it from the *QUEUE* and push it back on the *STACK*.

**Assumption:** time to move from source to destination for a machine is 1 minute. time to move back from destination to source for a machine is 1 minute.

Comment: What happens if a machine takes multiple trips ? U are not considering that case

Comment: That has still not been specified clearly in the question, whether same machine can carry multiple times or not